# $P[X=x]=0$ when $X$ is a continuous variable

Tags: probability, continuous-data, faq

I know that for any continuous variable $P[X=x]=0$.

But I can't visualize that if $P[X=x]=0$, there is an infinite number of possible $x$'s. And also why do their probabilities get infinitely small ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional probability of continuous variable](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/136523/conditional-probability-of-continuous-variable)

Comment: There are already two votes to close this question as duplicate. I don't agree. This is a pretty basic topic, one of those that will probably re-appear in the future, so it would be good if it had a direct and high quality answer, so we could refer to it in the future. The link provided by @Xi'an may be threated as duplicate but is also quite specific and hard to find via search. The link also does not provide an exhaustive answer, while this threat seems to converge to such. I think it should be left open as a future reference.

Comment: It might help to consider the inverse of this situation. Let $X$ be *any* random variable and let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number. There can be only a finite number of $\omega$ for which $\Pr(X=\omega)\ge\epsilon$, for otherwise--by adding up all these probabilities over disjoint events--you would conclude that the total probability is at least $\epsilon+\epsilon+\cdots$, which eventually exceeds $1$.  (This is the *Archimedean property* of real numbers.) This reasoning uses only three *axioms*: probabilities of disjoint events add, total probability is $1$, and the Archimedean axiom.

Comment: @whuber why not posting it as an answer? IMHO it is a very good answer.

Comment: @Tim Thank you, but I posted this thought as a comment, rather than an answer, because it's incomplete: I haven't figured out an elementary way to explain what happens in the limit as $\epsilon\to 0$. It seems to require some knowledge of cardinalities of infinite sets.

Comment: This question appears again and again on X validated, with the same arguments repeated. No point in more duplications.

Comment: @Xi'an I agree, but the thread you proposed is not a sufficiently close duplicate.  This is a difficult thing to search for.  Are you perhaps aware of other threads that duplicate this question?

Comment: Similar Qs: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/74692/probability-that-a-continuous-random-variable-assumes-a-fixed-point, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/481750/why-can-you-not-find-the-probability-of-a-specific-value-for-the-normal-distribu,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17000/probability-of-continuous-random-variable,

Answer (score 21):

Probabilities are models for the *relative frequencies* of observations. 
If an event $A$ is observed to have occurred $N_A$ times on $N$ trials, then its
relative frequency is
$$\text{relative frequency of }(A) = \frac{N_A}{N}$$
and it is generally believed that the numerical value of the above ratio
is a close approximation to $P(A)$ *when $N$ is "large"* where what is meant
by "large" is best left to the imagination (and credulity) of the reader.

Now, it has been observed that if our model of $X$ is that of a continuous
random variable, then the samples of $X$ $\{x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_N\}$ are
$N$ distinct numbers. Thus, the relative frequency of a specific number
$x$ (or, more pedantically, the event $\{X = x\}$) is either $\frac 1N$ if one of the $x_i$ has value $x$, or $\frac 0N$ if
all the $x_i$ are different from $x$.  If a more skeptical reader collects an additional
$N$ samples, the relative frequency of the event $\{X=x\}$ 
is either $\frac{1}{2N}$
or continues to enjoy the value $\frac 0N$.  Thus, one is tempted to guess
that $P\{X = x\}$ should be assigned the value $0$ since that is a good approximation to the observed relative frequency.

Note: the above explanation is (usually) satisfactory to engineers 
and others interested in
the application of probability and statistics (i.e. those who believe
that the axioms of probability were *chosen* so as to make the *theory*
a good model of reality), but totally unsatisfactory to many others.
It is also possible to approach your question from a
purely mathematical or statistical perspective and *prove* that $P\{X = x\}$
*must* have value $0$ whenever $X$ is a continuous random variable
via logical deductions from the axioms of probability, and without any 
reference to relative frequency or physical observations etc.

Comment: +1 "Note: the above explanation is... satisfactory to... those who believe that the axioms of probability were chosen so as to make the theory a good model of reality), but totally unsatisfactory...", in the internet's preferred phrasing, lol.

Comment: I don't understand what do you mean by *it has been observed that if $X$ is continuous, then ...*. How can we observe that ?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent That sentence is a little complicated, so it bears re-reading. Stripped of some parenthetical remarks, it says "it has been observed that ... the samples ... are $N$ distinct numbers." In other words, *when one assumes that $X$ has a continuous distribution*, then (almost surely) there will be no duplicates in any finite iid sample of $X$. That can be mathematically proven: it's not a mere observation.

Comment: @whuber Ok but then one cannot justify $\Pr(X=x)=0$ by this fact because one needs $\Pr(X=x)=0$ in order to prove it.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I think Dilip's remarks are being made in a different spirit than that. This answer is not an effort to provide a mathematically rigorous demonstration, but to provide some intuition and motivation for a fact that puzzles the OP. I am intrigued by this approach because it has such potential to bridge the gap between the discrete probability theory traditionally taught to beginners and the richer general theory of probability based on measure theory.

Comment: @whuber I understand the spirit, but at first glance I was not convinced that the no-ties property is more intuitive than the zero-probability property. For $N=2$ this is really the same thing: "$x_2 \text{ is never } x_1$" $\iff$  $\Pr(X_2=x_1)=0$.

Answer (score 18):

Let $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},P)$ be the underlying probability space. We say that a measurable function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is an absolutely continuous random variable if the probability measure $\mu_X$ over $(\mathbb{R},\mathscr{B})$ defined by $\mu_X(B)=P\{X\in B\}$, known as the distribution of $X$, is dominated by Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, in the sense that for every Borel set $B$, if $\lambda(B)=0$, then $\mu_X(B)=0$. In this case, the Radon-Nikodym theorem tells us that there is a measurable $f_X:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$, defined up to almost everywhere equivalence, such that $\mu_X(B)=\int_B f(x)\,d\lambda(x)$. Let $B=\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ be a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Since $\lambda$ is countably additive, $\lambda(B)=\lambda\left(\cup_{i\geq 1}\{x_i\}\right)=\sum_{i\geq 1}\lambda(\{x_i\})$. But
$$
  \lambda(\{x_i\}) = \lambda\left(\cap_{k\geq 1}[x_i,x_i+1/k)\right) \leq \lambda\left([x_i,x_i+1/n)\right) = \frac{1}{n} \, ,\qquad (*)
$$
for every $n\geq 1$. Due to the Archimedean property of the real numbers, since $\lambda(\{x_i\})\geq 0$,  the inequality $(*)$ holds for every $n\geq 1$ if and only if $\lambda(\{x_i\})=0$, entailing that $\lambda(B)=0$. From the assumed absolute continuity of $X$ it follows that $\mu_X(B)=P\{X\in B\}=0$.

Comment: Continuous random variable doesn't need to be absolutely continuous (it could have no density.)

Comment: Baloney. "Continuous random variable" is an informal name for "a random variable which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure". Hence, Radon-Nikodym guarantees that a density exists. A random variable with a singular distribution (e.g. Cantor) is a different thing. You're misleading potential students with your bogus comment.

Comment: When you criticized someone, please show the citation you referred to. Which probability text book said that *"Continuous random variable" is an informal name for "a random variable which is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure"*? In addition, this problem can be solved without requiring $X$ has a density, see my proof below.

Comment: Wikipedia disagrees with you, @Solitary: "[A continuous probability distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution#Continuous_probability_distribution) is a probability distribution that has a probability density function. Mathematicians also call such a distribution absolutely continuous [...]".

Comment: @amoeba Don't try to fool people. Zhanxiong was saying that, "*Continuous random variable doesn't need to be absolutely continuous*". On Wikipedia (cf. [Random Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable)), it says that, "*If the image is uncountably infinite (usually an interval) then $X$ is called a continuous random variable*", where $X$ is a measurable function from a measure space to some measurable space. We math students are **the most rigorous** ones, alright?

Answer (score 7):

$X$ is a continuous random variable means its distribution function ***$F$ is continuous***. This is the only condition we have but from which we can derive that $P(X = x) = 0$.

In fact, by continuity of $F$, we have $F(x) = F(x-)$ for every $x \in \mathbb{R}^1$, therefore:
$$P(X = x) = P(X \leq x) - P(X < x) = F(x) - F(x-) = 0.$$

Comment: If the distribution of a r.v. $X$ is Cantor, then its distribution function is continuous, but $X$ is a singular random variable; it's not a continuous random variable.

Comment: My friend, this actually can be a counterexample to your own answer, not mine. Since the existence of such ***Singular continuous*** r.v., it is necessary to distinguish ***absolute continuous*** r.v. and ***singular continuous*** r.v., although their distribution functions are all continuous. To equalize ***continuous*** r.v. and ***absolute continuous*** r.v. is ambiguous.

Comment: It isn't, but you won't hear, my friend.

Comment: By the way, you're actually "proving" that if $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$, then $P(X=x)=0$ for every $x$.

Answer (score 4):

**This is really a question about probabilities.**

It could be rephrased something like

> Suppose there are an infinite number of *disjoint* events. Why must their probabilities eventually become arbitrarily small?

Well, if they didn't become small, there would be a positive number $\epsilon$ smaller than all those probabilities.  One [axiom of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Third_axiom) implies the probability of a union of a *finite number* of distinct events is the sum of their probabilities.  Since "infinite" means there exist finite subsets of any size $n,$ we at least know that for any whole number $n$ there is a set of $n$ distinct events of probability $\epsilon$ or greater.  Taking $n \gt 1/\epsilon$ (guaranteed by the [Archimedean property of real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property)) we would deduce the existence of a collection of disjoint events whose probability exceeds $n\epsilon\gt 1,$ an obvious impossibility.  This completes the proof: we are obliged to conclude the original assumption is false: namely, the probabilities *do* become arbitrarily small.

BTW, it should be no mystery why an infinite number of disjoint events can *all* have zero probability.  Take the simplest kind of random variable: the constant $X=0.$  For any nonzero $x,$ obviously $\Pr(X=x) = 0.$  There are a lot of such $x$!  The problem really is,

> how can it be possible that $\Pr(X=x)=0$ for *all* possible values $x$ without forcing *all* probabilities to be zero?

The formal mathematical answer is buried in the probability axioms: they do not state, nor even imply, that the probability of an event must be the sum of the probabilities of all its elements.  This is the subtlety in the restriction to *countable* unions and *countable* sums.  The [real numbers are not countable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/237300/why-is-the-set-of-all-real-numbers-uncountable)

But then how do you visualize such a thing? The cumulative distribution function $F_X$ of any random variable $X$ is a useful tool. By definition, for any number $x,$ $F_X(x)$ is the chance that $X \le x,$ written $\Pr(X\le x).$  We can (and usually do) draw a graph of $F_X.$  The probability axioms imply its heights must lie between $0$ and $1$ (they are all probabilities, after all) and that the graph never decreases as you increase $x.$  (This latter is proven by noting that for $y\gt x,$ $F(y)-F(x) = \Pr(y \lt X \le x) \ge 0.$)

Using the CDF, then, we find that the probability of $X=x$ is the amount by which the graph of $F$ rises at $x$ as you move left to right.  In any *continuous* such graph, all such rises are zero (that's essentially the definition of "continuous").  Nevertheless, despite rising by an amount $0$ at every point $x,$ somehow the graph manages to increase its elevation from $0$ to $1$ throughout its domain.  See [Wikipedia (at "CDF")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) for some examples.  Pondering this visually evident fact might help you appreciate these issues better.  For a more insight, study [Zeno's Paradoxes](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/paradox-zeno/).

Answer (score 1):

There are many answers here which address the technical reasons for why infinitesimally small slices of a continuous probability distribution, $Pr(X=x)$, are 0. The key idea here is that this probability is uncountable.

Instead of adding to the mathematically driven answers here, I would like to connect this phenomenon to a real-world example (with a frequentist approach):

Imagine you are analyzing the (gaussian) distribution of temperatures for a particular time at a particular place. Let's say noon, Jan 1st, in Cambridge. Population: $\mu = 0$ and $\sigma = 10$

You can comfortably say that 95% of sample temperatures means will fall between ~ $-20$ and $20$. Shrink down that range and recompute your conf. interval. Rinse and repeat. Eventually, you are left with the interval of $-0.000001$ and $0.000001$.

What percentage of sample means would fall into that interval? A very small percentage in a technical sense, but in reality, most people would assign it $0$% upon some thought. How would you even measure such a precise temperature? As you continue to shrink the interval until both the positive and negative limits approach $0$, you'd need to find more and more precise measurement tools. Eventually, you'll run out of precision.

In truth, it's almost never going to be exactly 0 degrees at noon, and even if it were, you wouldn't have any way to measure it.

Thus, we assign zero probability to infinitesimally specific events in a continuous distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very simple. PDF is the density, then to get the probability you need to multiply it by the width of the region. So, when you get a smaller region around the point of interest $x$ the height of the density doesn't change, hence the probability is smaller and smaller while you squeeze the area around your point until it becomes exactly zero.

The difficult question is the reverse one, like this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/273407/36041

Comment: Although this is helpful, it would be good to note that not all continuous variables have densities: only absolutely continuous variables have them.