# On the definition of the Bayes Classifier

Tags: machine-learning, classification, bayesian, terminology

Let $(X,Y): \Omega \to (\mathbb{R}^d, F)$, with $F = \left\{ 1, \dots, n \right\}$ be a random variable. According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes_classifier) the Bayes classifier is $$C_B(x) = \arg\, \max \mathbb{P}(Y= i \,|\, X=x),$$
with $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Now I understand the idea, "pick the most likely one". However, if $X$ has a density, then $X=x$ is a zero probability event. How should conditioning on this event be understood?

Of course you can define something like $$\mathbb{P}(Y=i \,|\, X=x) = \lim \limits_{\varepsilon \to 0} \mathbb{P}(Y=i \, | \, X \in B(x, \varepsilon)),$$
where $B(x,\varepsilon)$ is a ball of radius $\varepsilon > 0$ around $x$, but I'm unable to find a reference for this.

Comment: While $\mathbb{P}(X=x)=0$, the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X=x$ is uniquely defined almost everywhere.

Comment: $P(Y=i \vert X=x)$ is to be interpreted as having observed $x$, what is the probability that it comes from class $i$. It is computed from $f(x\vert Y=i)p(Y=i)$, where we assume that the class conditional densities $f(x\vert Y=i)$ and prior probs $p(Y=i)$ are known in advance.

Comment: Recent related question: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246009/how-to-interpret-mathbbpba-when-mathbbpa-0