What is the best approach to explaining how to obtain point probabilities after introducing pdfs?
After explaining the use of probability density functions (pdfs) in hypothesis testing, I was asked about their use in obtaining a point probability (probability that the random variable assume a specific value). It seems to me that the best one can do is find the probability of the variable assuming a value within a range in very close proximity to that value, but never the value itself, and that this is still (or, more clearly) the case when one things about subtracting integrals (to represent areas under the curve) from one another. This being the case, I would welcome suggestions on how one should then migrate from the pdf model to a suitable alternative model when talking about point probabilities, assuming that talking about relative frequencies (numerator divided by denominator) is not a very natural transition when forming helpful links with prior learning on pdfs.

Welcome to Cross Validated! It is zero seems like a straightforward response.

Assuming an absolutely continuous random variable, this will be zero. There is not a lot more to be said about it.

(perhaps more properly stated: absolutely continuous distribution)

Check https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/298397/what-is-the-definition-of-probability-on-a-continuous-distribution and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142730/px-x-0-when-x-is-a-continuous-variable
