Sampling to maximise f(x)p(x)
I have a probability distribution $p(x)$ that I can generate samples form really easily. I also have some function $f(x)$ that I can calculate for each sample. My goal is to estimate the value of $x$ that maximises $f(x)p(x)$. I don't have an easy way of calculating $p(x)$ itself, and I would like to avoid using any KDE or anything to determine $p(x)$ from my samples.
One idea I had was to calculate a bunch of $f(x)$ for a lot of samples from $p(x)$, and then reject some of the samples based on the value of $f(x)$. But $f(x)$ has no lower bound so I'm not sure if this is the right option.
Clarification
I thought I would keep what I originally had so the comments make sense.

I am actually trying to optimize $f(x)P(x)+(1-P(x))f(0)$.
$x$ is some target I set on a control parameter.
$f(x)$ is always negative and not analytic. It represents the score I get if my target parameter of $x$ is actually achieved.
$P(x)$ represents the chance that a target control parameter is
achieved. If it is not instead of getting $x$ we get $0$.
$p(x)$ is the normalized version of $P(x)$, and maximizing $f(x)P(x)+(1-P(x)f(0)$ ends up being the same as maximizing $p(x)F(x)$ for $F(x)=f(x)-f(0)$ which is (in my case) positive everywhere (as $f(0)$ is the minimum of $f$).

My idea is to generate samples of $x$ from $p(x)$, this way they have already been rejected depending on how likely they are to be achieved (i.e. $P(x)$). I can then go through the samples and compute $F(x)$ for each sample, and reject it with some probability given by $F(x)/\max(F(x))$. I can then do something like KDE to find the maximum of my new distribution.
I believe this is a valid solution, but I don't love it. I end up needing to take a KDE anyway (at least this time over a nicer distribution) and this isn't super great. I was hoping there was another solution that could estimate the maximum more easily.

What sort of probability distribution $p(x)$ do you have? Why would you like to avoid KDE?

"and then reject some of the samples " You just end up with a sample that follows an alternative distribution and still have to do something like KDE to estimate the mode of that distribution. Whatever method you apply to find the mode, it might be smarter to use it without noisy rejection of samples (e.g. possibly you can use weights).

"But f(x) has no lower bound so I'm not sure if this is the right option." If $f(x)$ is at least positive somewhere, then you can use $max(0,f(x))$.

$p(x)$ is a multivariate zero inflated power normal distribution. I could in principle calculate $p(x)$ but its a pain. My concern with KDE is just that my distribution has a point mass at zero, but can't extend below zero.

I don't think the rejection sampling idea will work, I just put it there because I thought it might inspire something that would work. Yes KDE would eventually be needed there.

$f(x)$ is always less than zero so $\max(0, f(x))$ isn't a particularly fun function.

in that case maximizing the negative valued $f(x)p(x)$ is the same as minimizing the positive valued $-f(x)p(x)$. But, for many distribution functions that might be incredibly difficult because that minimum can be in a region with very small $p(x)$ which is difficult to estimate.

What sort of function is $f(x)$? An analytical solution might be possible, or at least figuring out some properties of $f(x)p(x)$ can be helpful.

You are speaking about this distribution? https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution or this one https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366d.htm ? In what way do you generalize it to a multivariate normal distribution? Why is it a pain to calculate or estimate the distribution?

@Sextus I had the same question.  Calculating probabilities for this distribution does require computing multivariate Normal probabilities over orthants (for the zero-inflated component); but there exist many fast, accurate software libraries to do that and the analytical expressions are tractable for theoretical analysis.  Another problem is that the zero-inflation makes the meaning of "$p(x)$" questionable, because this distribution does not have a density everywhere.  That makes it less than evident what this question is even trying to ask.

$f(x)$ is pretty complex and has to be evaluated numerically each time. It doesn't have a closed form expression.

I am speaking about the second one I believe, its on wiki as "Box-Cox" distribution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Cox_distribution.

Yeah your right, $p(x)$ is somewhat ill defined. My control parameter $x$ can either be zero or non-zero, when its non-zero it follows some density. I am wanting to optimise the expected value of $f(x)$ under the assumption that $p(x)$ is the "chance that $x$ is achieved". I've made a correction in my comment to @SextusEmpiricus that what I should have asked was to maximise $f(x)p(x)+(1-p(x)f(0)$

$f(x)$ might be ill-defined, but possibly there are ways to estimate it or transform it. That could be a solution path for specific cases.

Roughly speaking $f(x)=\mathbb{E}(\exp(\sum_i\alpha_i\ln(x_i))$ where $\alpha_i$ I only have samples for.

*„I am wanting to optimise the expected value of f(x) under the assumption that p(x) is the "chance that x is achieved".“ This $x$ is a discrete variable? Otherwise the chance is zero for a continuous distribution. Or do you want to integrate over all values of $x$ and compute the expectation value of $f(x)$? Instead of finding the single value of $x$ where $f(x)p(x)$ is maximum.

Ignoring the zero inflation part, because it doesn't make much sense. And I apologies because I have been very loose in my terminology, and in asking the question. I have a function $P(x)$ that returns a probability (between 0 and 1) of a particular value of $x$ being "achieved", $p(x)=AP(x)$ is just the normalized version of $P(x)$, I have been speaking of $p(x)$ because the constant $A$ ends up being meaningless when it comes to maximizing. I.e. the maximum of $f(x)P(x)+(1-P(x))f(0)$ is the same as $f(x)p(x)+(1-p(x))f(0)$. Which is the same as minimizing $p(x)(f(x)-f(0))$ which is $p(x)F(x)$

"...if my target parameter of x
is actually achieved." What does this 'achieved' mean. It is a bit confusing clarification, because for a probability density the probability for a specific value is zero $P[X=x]=0$ (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/142730/)


"and then reject some of the samples "

You end up with a sample that follows an alternative distribution $\propto f(x)p(x)$ and still have to do something like KDE to estimate the mode of that distribution.
Whatever method you apply to find the mode, it might be smarter to use it without noisy rejection of samples. For example with a kernel density estimation method you can use weights.

But f(x) has no lower bound so I'm not sure if this is the right option.

If f(x) has negative values, then you can set those at zero without changing the shape of the rest of the function. Ie. you can use max(0,f(x)).

The above is general. Ideally we know what sort of function $f(x)$ is and an analytical solution or improved algorithm might be possible. Or at least figuring out some properties of $f(x)p(x)$ can be helpful.
If there is really no easy closed form solution, then possibly using transformations might help as a solution path for specific cases.
If $f(x)p(x)$ is convex then a gradient descent search algorithm might be used.

Great point, I hadn't thought of that when I phrased the question. The actual function I am trying to maximise is $f(x)p(x)+f(0)(1-p(x))$. Essentially the problem I am solving is that I can set a target on the value of $x$, and the chance that it will be achieved is $p(x)$, otherwise $x=0$ (Its not actually always set $x=0$ but this doesn't matter I don't think).

@DBruwel $$f(x)p(x)+f(0)(1-p(x)) = f(0) + p(x) * (f(x)-f(0))$$ is this new function f(x)-f(0) positive in at least some point? Otherwise you get at least a local maximum in x=0 where the function that you maximise is zero. If there is some positive part then you can use $max(0,f(x)-f(0))$ as mentioned before in a comment (although this rejection sampling is not so effective and you still have to do density estimation afterwards)

"that I can set a target on the value of x" I don't know what that means.

Yeah $f(x)-f(0)$ is positive somewhere. And I think the max option works then. Thanks for all your help.

@DBruwel don't accept this question yet. I will have to rethink the situation and this answer was only for the special case $f(x)<0$.

Yeah sorry thats my bad, my question hasn't been particularly well phrased throughout. I can try and explain better somehow if you would like.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
